# C++: Using Recursion Transform characters

Tags: c++

I am making a Program which will convert a string using recursion.
The method replaces all occurrences of upper case characters with "1" all occurrences of "o" with 2 and all occurrences of "r" with a.

Requirement: The Recursive function should take only one Parameter that is the input string and returns the converted string.

Below is my code:

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<string>
    #include<string.h>
    using namespace std;

    int count=0;
    string convert(string a)
    {   
        int b=a.length();

        if(b>=count)
    {   
      if (isupper(a[b-(b-count)]))
      {
          a.replace(b-(b-count),1,"1");


          convert(a);
      }
      else if (a[b-(b-count)]=='o')
      {
          a.replace(b-(b-count),1,"2");  

           convert(a);
      }
      else if(a[b-(b-count)]=='r')
      {
           a.replace(b-(b-count),1,"a");


           convert(a);
      }

    }
        else
            return a;


    }


    void main()
    {
        string a;
        a="ABCrroo";
        int l=a.length();

        cout<<convert(a);

    getch();
    }
```

Comment: Why not check for `x >= 0 && x < a.size()`?

Comment: This `int x= b-(b-count);` is logically equivalent to `int x=count;`, that might help you figure out the problem.

Comment: No you see I have to check every character so this x=b-(b-count) is for finding the index e.g. = for the first index it will give 10-(10-0)=0 etc.

Comment: I am confirmed that error comes when the function tries to return the string. I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: Your "recursion" uses a global variable `count`.  I don't know if that is even acceptable.  A recursive routine should use local variables or parameters that are passed.  Having said that, this requirement to do this recursively seems hair-brained to me.

Comment: If I don't declare count globally and define count within the function then for every recursive call it will start from zero because without defining the counter it won't work. I am not confirmed but may be there's a logical mistake in my code.

Comment: @Qasim-nawaz don't define it globally, pass it as a parameter. Global variables are **never** the answer. **Never**.

Comment: Then it is not a true recursive function if you're relying on global variables.  There is no need for global variables in your case.  You may believe you need it, but you don't.  What you can do is call a base function that declares count locally, and have that base function call the actual recursive routine, passing the count as a parameter.

Comment: `string convert(string& str) { int count = 0; convertHelper(str, count); return str; }`  something like that.  It is `convertHelper` that will do the recursion, calling `convertHelper` each time.

Comment: I appreciate Your help. But I forgot to mention in my Question a requirement that is, the Recursive method should take a string transform the characters and returns the transformed string

Comment: and the method should take only one parameter that is the input string

Comment: can anyone translate the stipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `convert()` as returning a `std::string` but there are four places inside the function where you make a recursive call and *do nothing with the return value*. You have to do something if you want to pass the result of each recursive call back up the call stack.

I [modified your code](http://ideone.com/pskxej) and changed the four bare `convert(a);` lines to `return convert(a);` and it outputs "212a212a212a" which I think is the desired result.

It also looks like you are using an index one past the end of the string. The condition `if(b>=count)` would allow your code to use an index outside the valid range of `0..length-1`. Try changing it to just `if(b>count)`.

Comment: Can You please write that for me ? I didn't understand You just wrote return before every convert function call right? that didn't fixed my problem

Comment: @Qasim-nawaz: I hid a link to http://ideone.com/pskxej in my answer that shows the complete modified program compiled, executed, and the output. Thanks http://ideone.com!

Comment: Yeah I ran your code but the Problem Persists. I don't know why ? and yes the output is Correct

Comment: It gives an error Debug assertion failed Line 1441 
Expression subscript out of range

Comment: @Qasim-nawaz: Try changing the `if` condition from `b>=count` to `b>count`. When `b==count` it will access an index one-past-the-end of the string.

Comment: Yes that Fixed my problem. I tried b>count in my last code but that didn't fixed my problem so I came here. Code of ideone + b>count fixed my problem Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
string convert1(string a, int pos);
using namespace std;
int count=0;

string convert1(string a, int pos)
{ 
    if(pos < a.length())
    {
        if(isupper(a[pos])) a.replace(pos, 1, "1");
        else if(a[pos]=='o') a.replace(pos, 1, "2");
        else if(a[pos]=='r') a.replace(pos, 1, "a");
        convert1(a, ++pos);
    }
    else return a;
}


int main()
{
    string a="oYoroCoroSor";

    cout << a << endl;
    int l=a.length();

    cout<< convert1(a, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No I have to do it using Recursion Only.

Comment: @Qasim-nawaz Modified the answer. Just pass the starting index using an extra parameter in the recursive function.

Comment: As I said in the above comments that " I forgot to mention in my Question a requirement that is, the Recursive method should take a string transform the characters and returns the transformed string ". Also the function type should be a string and the function should take only one parameter(string)  and returns the transformed string 

Can you help me with that ?

Comment: string convert(string a)
{
    string b = a;
    convert1(b, 0);
    return b;
}

This function fulfills your requirement.

Comment: I don't Understand are you using Two functions.?  IF yes then which one is doing the recursion ?

Comment: Sorry, but your current answer doesn't fulfills my requirement.